# Is it possible to save JavaScript generated images on the serverside?

Tags: javascript, image, save, server-side

I want to use JSChart (http://www.jscharts.com/) to generate a dynamic chart.

It uses a `<canvas>` object.

Furthermore I want to save the generated Chart as an image (to put in a pdf file) on the serverside.

Is it possible to save a JavaScript generated image as jpg or png on the serverside?

Preferably the solution should work with Ruby and Ruby On Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this uses a `<canvas>` object to render the charts, can't tell without downloading and it requires registration, so no.  If it does, perhaps take a look at [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/), that returns the canvas as a data URL, base64 encoded image, which could be sent back to the server via an AJAX call.

Comment: @ayckoster: Note that IE clients that do not have `<canvas>` use [excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) I believe, which I do not think has the functionality, though it may be implementable, see the [issue thread on it](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=41).

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/ on the server to convert an SVG. It's the method used by highcharts to convert the graph generated by the application. See http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server